# Document getting corrupted when created using custom template from Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a List on which a workflow is running. I have a document library with custom template applied to it. I am creating a document (with custom template) in the document library when an item is added in the list.

The document gets created but when I try to open it, it gives an error "Sorry, Word App ran into a problem opening this document. To view this document please open it in word."
When I open it in word (desktop version), the document opens but the content is blank (content in the template does not appear).

I tried creating content type and then applying template to that content type and creating a document with this new content type, still the same issue. 
I also tried creating a normal document (without any custom template) through the workflow, still the same issue.

Any particular reason for this? Am I doing something wrong? Is there any NO-CODE alternative to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When we use workflow action to create a document, we need to update or edit the document template’s extension from .dotx to .docx for the custom content type.

Comment: Tried that. Still not working.